# I am building apk using capacitor from vue.js project. on android it is can run on emulater but when I building to apk I encounterd some errors

Tags: android, iphone, vue.js, ionic-framework, capacitor

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

D:\Work Space\famous-aehenao\famous-aehenao\app\android\app\build\intermediates\tmp\manifest\androidTest\debug\tempFile1ProcessTestManifest15253197995702436303.xml:27:9-33:20 Error:
android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$BootstrapActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
D:\Work Space\famous-aehenao\famous-aehenao\app\android\app\build\intermediates\tmp\manifest\androidTest\debug\tempFile1ProcessTestManifest15253197995702436303.xml:34:9-40:20 Error:
android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$EmptyActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
D:\Work Space\famous-aehenao\famous-aehenao\app\android\app\build\intermediates\tmp\manifest\androidTest\debug\tempFile1ProcessTestManifest15253197995702436303.xml:41:9-47:20 Error:
android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$EmptyFloatingActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.